# problemas traduccion de consulta eloquen laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

Buen dia...

He tratado de traducir esta consulta pero no me funciona en eloquen

```html
select * from usuarios where usuario_ad='danielad' and user_id;
```

Debo estar cometiendo un pequeño error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te consulta en SQL puro, esta incompleta por que te hace falta igualar el `user_id` con algo; por ejemplo poner así:

`user_id = 1`

Con lo anterior ya estaría completa la sentencia; ahora pasandola primero al query Builder Fluent de Laravel te quedaría así:

```
$data = \DB::table('usuarios')
        ->where('usuario_ad', 'danielad')
        ->where('user_id', 2)
        ->get();
```

Es decir en el código anterior, la iguale el `user_id` con 2 como mero ejemplo

Ahora esa misma consulta con Eloquent

```
$data = User::where('usuario_ad', 'danielad')
         ->where('user_id', 2)
         ->get();
```

Simplemente sistituí el Facade `\DB` con el nombre del modelo, que en este caso puse `User` pero que debe tener si es que lo tienes el que tu hayas declarado

Por otro lado como punto final, para lograr esto

```
where(.....) AND(.......)
```

En laravel solo debes encadenar por ejemplo el accedo a dos métodos `where` de este modo

`where()
->where()`

Comment: Haa faltaba el get(),  y si tienes razon la consulta esta incompleta... ahora ya funciona como necesitaba .. gracias shadow